Characterizing one-sided M-projections on real C*-algebras
Let $A$ be a real C*-algebra, and let $P: A \to A$ be a bounded linear projection. We say that $P$ is a left M-projection if the map
$$
v_P: A \to C_2(A), \quad x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} P(x) \\ x - P(x) \end{pmatrix}
$$
is an isometry, where $C_2(A)$ denotes the space of column matrices with entries in $A$, equipped with a suitable norm.
Is there a characterization of left $M$-projections on real C*-algebras that relies solely on the Banach space structure of $A$ and avoids the use of operator space concepts?
During my investigation into the relationship between left M-projections and the Jordan algebraic structure of real C*-algebras, I specifically explored whether the range of a left M-projection, $P(A)$, was necessarily a Jordan ideal in $A$. Recall that a subspace $J$ of a Jordan algebra $A$ is a Jordan ideal if $J \circ A \subseteq J$, where $\circ$ denotes the Jordan product.
Initially, it seemed plausible that $P(A)$ might always be a Jordan ideal. This intuition stemmed from the fact that in the complex case, the range of a left M-projection on a C-algebra is always a left ideal, which is a stronger condition than being a Jordan ideal. However, my exploration revealed that this property does not hold in general for real C-algebras.
Here is a counterexample:
Consider the real C*-algebra $A = M_2(\mathbb{R})$, the algebra of 2x2 matrices with real entries. Let $P: A \to A$ be the projection defined by
$$
P\left(\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
It can be shown that $P$ is a left M-projection. However, the range of $P$ is
$$
P(A) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} : a \in \mathbb{R} \right\}.
$$
Now, consider the element $x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in A$ and the element $y = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in P(A)$. Their Jordan product is
$$
x \circ y = \frac{1}{2}(xy + yx) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \notin P(A).
$$
This demonstrates that $P(A)$ is not a Jordan ideal in $A$.
So is a characterization of left $M$-projections on real C*-algebras that avoids the use of operator space concepts impossible?
